# Error while adding items to treeview C#

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, sql-server-ce

I have written the following code to create a tree view:
it reads data from a sqlCEserver and generates view according. It was working fine before i entered the inner while loop to add sub items in header.

```
private void ClientTree_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
            string moduleCat = null;
            string Cname = null;
            SqlCeConnection _con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\Family\Desktop\Tranchulas projects\ControlCenter\ControlCenter\bin\Debug\ClientDB.sdf");
            _con.Open();
            SqlCeDataReader _reader = null;
            SqlCeDataReader _reader1 = null;
            SqlCeCommand readMod = new SqlCeCommand(@"SELECT DISTINCT ModuleID FROM ClientRecord", _con);

            _reader = readMod.ExecuteReader();
            while(_reader.Read())
            {

                moduleCat = _reader["ModuleID"].ToString();

                treeItem = new TreeViewItem();
                treeItem.Header = moduleCat;

                SqlCeCommand readName = new SqlCeCommand(@"SELECT Cname FROM ClientRecord WHERE (ModuleID = '" + moduleCat + @"')", _con);
                _reader1 = readName.ExecuteReader();
                while (_reader1.Read())
                {
                    Cname = _reader["Cname"].ToString();
                    treeItem.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = Cname });
                    ClientTree.Items.Add(treeItem);
                }
            }
        }
```

it gave this exception:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message='Initialization of 'System.Windows.Controls.TreeView' threw an exception.' Line number '10' and line position '99'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  LineNumber=10
  LinePosition=99
```

line number 10 is:

```
<TreeView x:Name="ClientTree" Height="350.4" Width="164.2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Initialized="ClientTree_Initialized" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is gone when you comment out the inner while-loop, then it can't be a problem in the xaml. (Because there's nothing changed) Right?? But, your exceptions states that it ís a xamlParseException, weird.

The best you can do here is putting the line InitializeComponent() in a try-catch statement and set a breakpoint in the catchblock. Now you have access to the complete stacktrace with al innerexception info you need!
Good luck.

The InitializeComponent is in the contructor in code-behind.

```
try
{
  InitializeComponent();
}
catch ( Exception ex )
{
  // set breakpoint here, and watch StackTrace
}
```

Comment: yes nothing is changed!
I tried the try-catch statement, It never catches any exception.
Can you suggest any alternative way of adding item in the header?